# Cake PHP div refresh server crashed

Tags: ajax, cakephp, crash, server

I'm using `cake php`

For 8 times I have used div refresh pattern from the server but after few minutes my server crashed and I have to ask the server provider to reopen the server.

What would be the best way to proceed if I want to use the database through div refresh?

```
function check()
{
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo $this->webroot;?>'+'Bookings/rand_f',
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {},
        cache : false,
        success:function(result){
            $('#ht').html(result);
            $("#session_value").val(result);
    }});
}
setInterval(check, 1000);

function check_count()
{
    var a=$("#session_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo $this->webroot;?>'+'Bookings/check_count/'+a,
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {},
        cache : false,
        success:function(result){
            if(result=='change'){
                $('#res').val(result);
                listings_live1();
            }else{
                $('#res').val('no_change');
            }
    }});    
}
setInterval(check_count, 1000);

function listings_live1()
{
    var a=$("#session_value").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo $this->webroot;?>'+'Bookings/listingsbookingcheck/'+a,
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {},
        cache : false,
        success:function(result){
            var x=  $('#live_listing').html(result);
            if(x){
                return 1;
            }
    }});
}

function check_count_all()
{
    var x=$("#last_count_all").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo $this->webroot;?>'+'Bookings/check_count_all',
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {},
        cache : false,
        success:function(result){
            $("#count_all").val(result);
            if(result!=x){
                listings_liveall();
                $("#last_count_all").val(result);
                $("#st").val('change');
            }
            else{
                $("#st").val('nochange');
            }
    }});
}
setInterval(check_count_all, 1000);

function listings_liveall()
{ 
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo $this->webroot;?>'+'Bookings/listingall',
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {},
        cache : false,
        success:function(result){
            $('#listings_liveall').html(result);
    }});
}

function showaction(str,id){
    $("#boking_status_call_cancel").show();
    $("#alertshow").html('Are you sure you want to '+str+' this Booking?');
    if(str!='accept'){
        $("#reject_reason").show();
    }else{
        $("#reject_reason").hide();
    }
    $("#role_call").val(str+','+id);
}

function update_mobile_booking(){
    var strcall=$("#role_call").val();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : '<?php echo $this->webroot;?>'+'Bookings/update_booking_mobile/'+strcall,
        dataType : 'html',
        data: {},
        cache : false,
        success:function(result){
            var x=listings_live1();
            if(x==1){
                listings_liveall();
            }
    }});
}

/*settimeout page load mobile booking*/
var myFunc = function() {
    listings_live1();
    listings_liveall();
}
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(myFunc, 1000);
}
/*
function check_counter_upper(){
    c1=$("#session_value").val();
    c2=$("#count_chk_cl").val();
    if(c1!=c2 && c2!='undefined'){
        listings_live1();
        $("#st1").val('force_change');
    }else{
        $("#st1").val('no_force_change');
    }
}

setInterval(check_counter_upper, 4000);*/
```

Comment: Altered to use grown up language.

Comment: This code is just client side javascript when you mention cakephp, is out of context and therefor makes no sense as is, is terribly presented, we have no idea what goes wrong and your server quits and in general you've put no effort to explain in order to get help.